# Можно ли дать один IP адрес разным контейнерам Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

У меня есть несколько контейнеров, висящих на разных портах.
Приложение раньше работало на одном хосте и соответственно несколько служб обменивалось данными по разным портам на локалхосте.

Есть ли вариант дать один ip адрес для всех контейнеров, через Dockerfile или docker-compose?

Comment: А может проще  будет сделать, что бы они не локалхосту обращались, а по имени контейнера? тогда можно произвольно  будет разносить

Comment: @KoVadim пока вопрос стоит именно "дать нескольким контейнерам один ip адрес". Может звучит и глупо, но пока именно так =)

Comment: И как операционной системе разбрасывать пакеты? одинаковый айпи можно дать, если они  в разных подсетях. Но это вряд ли то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: кратко: дать-то можно, но связи, конечно, не будет. специально для multihosting-а докеровцы придумали [swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Докер предлагает решать эту пробему с помошью режима swarm. Сделайте ваш главный хост менеджером роя:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2377
```

Хотя если вы используете docker-compose он скорее всего у вас уже в режиме swarm.

Выполните для генерации команды подключения второго хоста в качестве рабочего

```
docker swarm join-token worker
```

или в качестве резервного менеджера

```
docker swarm join-token manager
```

Скопируйте полученную команду и выполните ее на втором хосте, подключив второй хост к swam:

```
docker swarm join --token <какой-то токен> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2377
```

Разверните ваши сервисы используя docker-compose на одном из менеджеров. 
Докер обещает, что все ваши сервисы через `load balancer` будут видны по IP любого из хостов, а так же разворачивать и администрировать ваше приложение можно обращаясь к любому менеджеру, как будто все сервисы находятся на одной ноде.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]